# Reading XML elements using C#

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0

How do I get the FirstName, LastName and OtherName on the below sample xml file? I need to assign them to a variable from behind code using C#.

```
  <PatientRecord>
      <Demographics>
              <Names>
                     <cdsd:LegalName namePurpose="L">
                               <cdsd:FirstName>
                                     <cdsd:Part>SARAH</cdsd:Part>
                                     <cdsd:PartType>GIV</cdsd:PartType>
                               </cdsd:FirstName>
                               <cdsd:LastName>
                                      <cdsd:Part>GOMEZ</cdsd:Part>
                                      <cdsd:PartType>FAMC</cdsd:PartType>
                               </cdsd:LastName>
                               <cdsd:OtherName>
                                       <cdsd:Part>GABRIELA</cdsd:Part>
                                       <cdsd:PartType>GIV</cdsd:PartType>
                               <cdsd:PartQualifier>BR</PartQualifier>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ReadXML .net function such as:

```
DataSet objDataSet = new DataSet();

objDataSet.ReadXML("@PathofXMLfile", XmlReadMode.InferSchema);

List<object> Names = objDataSet.Tables["FirstName"].AsEnumerable().Select(r => r["Part"]).ToList();
```

This should apply all rows of data in the same tag structure (i.e.: `<cdsd:Part>SARAH</cdsd:Part>`) into a object list, then you can use a loop to get each value or specify Names[x] to retrieve a value at a specific index.  Note: I am not certain if the ReadXML function will remove the tag prefix (cdsd:) or if you will need to include that in the lambda expression i.e.: `List<object> Names = objDataSet.Tables["cdsd:FirstName"].AsEnumerable().Select(r => r["cdsd:Part"]).ToList();`

Answer (score 0):

Load your XML document into an `XmlDocument` type object and use `XPath` query the FirstName, LastName etc.

E.g.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(yourXmlstring);

XmlNode firstNameNode = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/PatientRecord/Demographics/Names/cdsd:LegalName/cdsd:FirstName"); 

string firstName = firstNameNode.InnerText;
```

[Here's](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307548) a step by step guide for reading XML document.

Answer (score 0):

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(stream);
var legalNames = xml.Root
                    .Elements("Demographics")
                    .Elements("Names")
                    .Elements("LegalName");
foreach(XElement ln in legalNames)
{
    string firstName = (string)ln.Element("FirstName");
    // or you can get (string)ln.Element("FirstName").Element("Part");
    string lastName = (string)ln.Element("LastName");
    string otherName = (string)ln.Element("OtherName");
}
```

for more information see [Programming Guide (LINQ to XML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb387087%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)